# ParseExact date time in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, datetime

When my debugger reaching this point it is giving as

> not valid date time

**Code:**

```
DateTime oDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(
  expDate, 
 "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`expDate` date contains date

```
"13-May-22 13:24:00".
```

I tried googling it but didn't got it satisfied help

Comment: At a glance, your input string doesn't satisfy the `M`, `dd`, `yyyy`, and `tt` components.

Comment: `13-May-22 13:24:00` is nothing at all like `"M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", so the error is correct.  `ParseExact` means the data will be in the **exact** format specified

Comment: The format is either `d-MMM-yy H:m:s` or `d-MMMM-yy H:m:s` depending on if `May` is abbreviated or not.

Comment: For reference, [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) is what you'd consult for the meaning of each of those individual format specifiers.  After doing so you'll find that your input string is way off from what your format string expects and can then use the same resource to build a compliant format string.

Answer (score 1):

There's an *ambiguity* in the example provided:

```
13-May-22 13:24:00
    ^
  Is this abbreaviated ("Apr", "May", "Jun") or not ("April", "May", "June")?
```

If month `May` is abbreviated (like `Apr`, `Jun`) or not (like `April`, `June`). To embrace *both* possibilities we should try two formats:

```
d-MMM-yy H:m:s   # abbreviated month
d-MMMM-yy H:m:s  # full month
```

**Code:**

```
string expDate = "13-May-22 13:24:00";

var oDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(expDate, 
  new string[] { "d-MMM-yy H:m:s", "d-MMMM-yy H:m:s" }, 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

If you know how to solve the ambiguity, you can simplify the code, e.g. if month is abbreviated

```
var oDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(expDate, 
  "d-MMM-yy H:m:s",  
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```